# linking error in friend function of a template class

Tags: c++, copy-and-swap

I have template class node and in order to follow the [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom i am tryig to write the `swap` function which is a `friend` of class `Node`

my code is :

`Node.h`

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include<memory>
template<typename type>
class Node
{
    type data_;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next_;
public:
    Node(type data);
    Node(const Node& other);
    Node& operator=(Node other);
    friend void swap(Node& lhs, Node& rhs);
};

#include "Node.tpp"
#endif
```

and the `Node.tpp`

```
template<typename type>
Node<type>::Node(type data):data_(data),next_(nullptr){
}

template<typename type>
Node<type>::Node(const Node& other)
{
    data_ = other.data_;
    next_ = nullptr;
    if(other.next_ != nullptr)
    {
        next_.reset(new Node(other.next_->data_));
    }
}
template<typename type>
void swap(Node<type>& lhs, Node<type>& rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.data_,rhs.data_);
    swap(lhs.next_,rhs.next_);
}

template<typename type>
Node<type>& Node<type>::operator=(Node other)
{
    swap(*this,other);
    return *this;
}
```

when i test it from `Source.cpp`

```
#include "Node.h"
int main()
{
    Node<int> n(3);
    Node<int> n2(n);
    Node<int> n3(5);
    n3 = n2;
}
```

i am getting the following **linking error** :

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl swap(class Node<int> &,class Node<int> &)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend declaration doesn't "inherit" the template parameter, but needs its own:

```
template<typename type>
class Node
{
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    template<typename U> // <<<<<<<<<<<
    friend void swap(Node<U>& lhs, Node<U>& rhs);
                      // ^^^           ^^^
    // ...
};
```

Comment: i am sorry but can you kindly elaborate a little . i am not exactly able to grasp completely.

Comment: @Hummingbird Clearer now?

Comment: @Hummingbird THX for the edit. I'm never sure where to place the `friend` keyword in that case.